# Trouble with image import using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, tailwind-css

I am completely new to the world of the world of web developing. I took a crash course on React JS , Tailwind CSS and Three.js.

I have a data.jsx file and I am trying to import images from workspace folders to add to the webpage. Here is the code:

```js
// skills images
import SkillImg1 from "./assets/img/skills/Microsoft.png";
import SkillImg2 from "./assets/img/skills/python.png";
import SkillImg3 from "./assets/img/skills/R.png";
import SkillImg4 from "./assets/img/skills/Tableau.png";
import SkillImg5 from "./assets/img/skills/sql.png";
```

Then I defined an array within the same file:

```js
// skill
export const skills = [
  {
    image: SkillImg1,
  },
  {
    image: SkillImg2,
  },
  {
    image: SkillImg3,
  },
  {
    image: SkillImg4,
  },
  {
    image: SkillImg5,
  },
];
```

Then I have a skills.jsx file for formatting the images to the webpage.

Here is the code contained within the file:

```js
import React from "react";
import { inViewHandler } from "../animationHandler";
import { motion, useAnimation } from "framer-motion";
import { InView } from "react-intersection-observer";
import { skills } from "../data";

export const Skills = () => {
  const animation = useAnimation();



  return (
    <inView onChange={(inView) => inViewHandler(inView, animation)}>
      <section className="h-76 bg-primary py-12">
        <div className="container mx-auto">
          <motion.div
            className="grid grid-cols-6 md:grid-flow-row"
            initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.5 }}
            animate={animation}
          >
            {skills.map((skill, index) => {
              return (
                <div className="max-h-xs" key={index}>
                  <img src={skill.image} alt="" loading="lazy" />
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </motion.div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </inView>
  );
};
```

*** I am also providing animationHandler.js code for more context: **

```js
import { inView } from "framer-motion";

export const inViewHandler = (inView, animation) => {
    if (inView) {
        animation.start({ opacity: 1, scale: 1, transition: { duration: 1 } });
    }
};
```

**Does anybody have a fix? **

**The file formats of the images are in png. Here's what I have tried so far: **

1. changed the file path to "../assets/img/skills/[file_name]"
2. changed the file path to "src/assets/img/skills/[file_name]"
3. triple checked relative path, file extensions and names.
4. changed resolution to 72x72 pixel/inch and dimensions to 96x96 px

Both of these changes received the same error - Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "../assets/img/skills/Microsoft.png" from "src/data.jsx". Does the file exist?

For some reason, file paths that look like this work: ./assets/img/skills/Microsoft.png

Any other change is causing an internal server error.

The only file path that works is: ./assets/img/skills/[file_name]

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the path of the image relative to the component that is calling it.

```
// skill
    export const skills = [
      {
        image: SkillImg1,
      },
      {
        image: SkillImg2,
      },
      {
        image: SkillImg3,
      },
      {
        image: SkillImg4,
      },
      {
        image: SkillImg5,
      },
    ];
```

instead try

```
// skill
    export const skills = [
      {
        image: ${enter path according to skill.jsx file},
      },
      ...
      ...
    ];
```